# How use orderBy() in laravel relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I have class List and Post, they have relation `belongsToMany` with pivot table.

1)list:

```
id
name
type_order //1- sort post by rating, 2 - by id, 3 - by random
```

2)post:

```
id
text
```

3)list_post

```
id
list_id
post_id
```

How realize sortBy for with param(type_order) when I show `feeds` with relations `post`?
Maybe usign Scope?

Answer (score 0):

Please reffer this link : `https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset`

And what i understand according to your question the answer is -

```
List::with('post')->where('list.id','3')->orderBy('list.type_order','desc')->get();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I use Feed controller and from show($feed) i get which post belongs to feed.

Comment: So you saying that you have Feed model and Post belongs to Feed. Right?

Comment: okay, Are you passing feed id in it and do you want feed list with all the post belongs to that feed in which order ?

Comment: In order that which store in if Feed model - type_order.

Comment: ya i know order by type_order but in which order ascending/ descending.

Comment: let it be ascending

Comment: then do it like this Feed::with('post')->where('feed.id','3')->orderBy('feed.type_order','asc')->get();

Comment: Ok, but when I want to see feed without relation post?

Comment: Just remove 'with' and use like this Feed::where('id','3')->orderBy('type‌​_order','asc')->get(‌​);

Comment: But in request I can add param of relation such pictures, tags and other.your solution means that realtion with post well be obligatory